# Функция и возврат значения в Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com

Есть функция, проверяющая существует ли запись в базе `parse.com`:

```
func checkObject (login:String) {
    let object = PFQuery(className: "MapObject")
    object.whereKey("User", equalTo: login)
    object.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if objects! == [] {
            var typeofuser = false
            print(typeofuser)
        } else {
            var typeofuser = true
            print(typeofuser)
        }
    }
}
```

Ее вызов прикручен на кнопку и она работает правильно. Но я хочу ее изменить таким образом, что бы она возвращала `typeofuser`, т.е. `true` или `false`. Попытки добавить `-> Bool` и `return typeofuser` вызывает ошибку. Подскажите, какой правильный синтаксис?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что метод `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` асинхронный, соответственно не известно, сколько времени займет исполнение этой функции и что более важно приложение не будет ждать пока она закончится, а сразу перейдет к исполнению следующей строки кода. Я предлагаю изменить таким образом:

```
func checkObject (login:String, completionHandler : (typeofuser : Bool) -> ()) {
  let object = PFQuery(className: "MapObject")
  object.whereKey("User", equalTo: login)
  object.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
    if objects! == [] {
      completionHandler(typeofuser : false)
    } else {
      completionHandler(typeofuser : true)
    }
  }
}
```

Использовать можно так

```
var checkResult : Bool?

checkObject("login") { typeofuser in
  checkResult = typeofuser
}
```

Обрати внимание, что  `checkResult` типа `Optional` потому, что на момент когда она тебе может понадобиться не факт, что запрос к базе данных успеет обработаться.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Функция возвращает true или false. Но у меня сразу возникает следующий вопрос: как ее вызвать, что бы результат вызова засунуть в какую то переменную для дальнейшего анализа? Пока вызываю так.   

     checkObject(textLoginName) {
    (result:Bool) in
    print(result)
    }

Comment: См. дополненный ответ

Comment: Спасибо. С вызовом функции происходит какая то загадка. В первом способе всегда возврате nil. Во втором - правильно                              //первый способ
  var result :Bool?
  checkObject(textLoginName) {typeofuser in result = typeofuser}
  print(result)
 
  //второй способ
  checkObject(textLoginName) {
  (result:Bool) in
  print("second way \(result)")
  }

Comment: Я же написал, что `result` и будет `nil` до тех пор, пока не произойдет соединения с сервером. Я рекомендую почитать об асинхронном программировании.

Comment: Это я понял. Я не понимаю, почему в первом способе вызова функция не успевает получить ответ, а во втором успевает?

Comment: Все-таки не совсем понял. В первом случае спрашивается текущий статус `result`, когда ответ от б/д еще возможно не получен. А во втором - `print` вызывается как только ответ получен.